# Please use the new reCaptcha on the human verification dialog

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, captcha

I posted a question this morning and got this beauty of a Captcha:

> [image: Can you read that?]

Can you read that? Go ahead, get your glasses. Still no?

We can fix this: [Google announced a new reCaptcha API that is **captcha-less**](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html). It looks like this:

> [image: No words]

Instead of staring down some distorted words and numbers, we could be clicking on cat pictures (When they "can't confidently predict whether a user is a human or an abusive agent" checking the box):

> [image: kitten war, but to replace a captcha]

Since I -- among others -- receive the human verification dialog often, I ask the following:

### Will Stack Exchange implement [the new reCaptcha API](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/)?

Comment: We are looking into it - don't forget, it was _just_ rolled out.

Comment: +1, we need moar cats!!!1!!eleven!!!1!

Comment: These cats were not paid for their modeling work. I don't support that catastrophe! But I do support your proposal. +1

Comment: object classification seems more fun than OCR. Let me in!

Comment: @Scimonster we (google) need(s) more unicorns!!!

Comment: @CRABOLO Nice meme

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**This is now live network wide.**  I have yet to see any cat pictures though, so I'm a bit disappointed.

You can add `?captcha=1` to any question and edit it to test it out.  Please let me know if you see any issues!

If the `?captcha=1` does not work, go to `http://[site].com/nocaptcha` to trigger the per-site Captcha, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/nocaptcha for Stack Overflow.

Comment: didn't you mean to write "Please let me know if you see any cat pictures"?

Comment: [This user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278633/captcha-broken-on-stack-overflow-no-challenge-shown) appears to have had issues but was using an extension whitelisting 3rd-party domains. I've [updated the 'requirements' FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/71208/revisions) here to include `gstatic.com` and `apis.google.com` as they were not yet part of the list.

Comment: Hm, still get illegible ones on old-ish browsers.

Comment: The `?captcha=1` didn't work, I got to see it by loading a questio, pasting answer from clipboard within a second and submitting right away.

Comment: You can also visit:  http://stackoverflow.com/nocaptcha

Comment: @Geoff http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245657/a-box-is-now-a-captcha

Comment: Looks like it's [the same old same after all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248326/i-am-unable-to-solve-the-recaptcha) - as bad as before.

Comment: Error occurred while submitting captcha. Great.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas I officially ask for a captcha that asks users to chose all the Fluttershy faces among the other ponies.