# There is no need in "I'm a Human Being" button in the new captcha

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, captcha

The new captcha [was just rolled out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244726) there.

> [image: new captcha!!!]

There seems to be no issues with it, but there is no need in "I'm a Human Being" button. If you click it without doing anything else, it will lead to an error:

> [image]

(which is understandable - I didn't solve any captcha)

If you click the checkbox and pass the verification, this button is automatically greyed out and shows black dots; in a second captcha is gone.

> [image]

(Similar behaviour will be if it asks you for text: once you solve it and click "verify", captcha is gone, no need in "I'm a Human Being" button)

So I feel that this button should be removed.

Comment: If anyone knows, could you press Enter with the previous method while typing the letters?

Comment: oops, misread. Thought you're asking same thing - my bad, retracted.

Comment: If that wasn't there, Aliens would make it past that screen. Aliens.

Comment: Only a robot would claim to be a "Human Being". Real humans know enough to say they're not robots.

Comment: @Shog9 have you _met_ real humans? :-P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This button is there for scrapers and bots that click submit buttons automatically.  We want them to get caught in our nasty web of lies.

Comment: Ok, but why not make it display:none then

Comment: "This button is there for scrapers and bots" I swear! I'm not a bot! Maybe some mischievous being, but not a bot.

Comment: It needs to look as much like a typical form as any other on the internet - with a visible submit button.

Comment: Funny trick... But only *imagine*, what if Community is reading it now... It will brake all the things there.