# What's with the CAPTCHAs?

Tags: support, captcha

I was just trying to answer something on SF with answers from Unix.SE, since I was researching the same topic. I did that with an older browser from my old laptop at home.

I was presented a reCAPTCHA with lots of… well, it looked welsh, it did not have any vocals for sure, and some of the things looked mirrored. I hit reload about 40-50 times, tried to enter about half a dozen of them, but was denied.

The audio version sounds like a cross between white noise and moaning to me. Note I'm not an English native speaker, in fact it's only my third natural language I learned, and I learned it mostly read/write, so I could not understand a thing.

I tried another browser, but it just crashed upon loading the site. (Known issue with https in that one, though.)

So I copy/pasted that to my box at work via VPN, logged into it via VNC, and ran a modern Firefox 31 on that. I was, again, presented with a captcha… with nothing to enter. OK, RequestPolicy (something I don't have at home). I tell it to temporarily accept anything, and get a mere checkbox “I'm not a robot”. WTF?

Anyway, posted the answer. But I would **really** appreciate it if the site engineers could dig out, say, Opera 9.27 and try to use this site with that, every once in a while. And if something can be done about these absolutely indecipherable CAPTCHAs. Now assume I was blind, I could not have posted *at all* due to the “funny” audio part.

I understand this is not a priority, but *please*!

Update: screenshot added
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: [Better captchas should be here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244638/please-use-the-new-recaptcha-on-the-human-verification-dialog).

Comment: And Opera 9 is [not supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208).

Comment: @MartijnPieters “This is now live network wide” on Dec 5, although it is now Dec 13, and I have been having these troubles. Hmm. Maybe that's only for the latest browsers? ☹☹☹ • @ Opera 9: Yes I know, but it still works, it's the best my system at home has, and in contrast to my normal browser (Lynx) it even does JS more or less nicely, so…

Comment: You'd have to ask Google; it will indeed still fall back to the classic reCAPTCHA if it deems you still need to be tested more thoroughly.

Comment: @mirabilos: presumably you never were shown [this checkbox](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-wt7yljKcU_8/VH5MJTUCBOI/AAAAAAAAACw/WKqE3ixUUdw/s1600/Recaptcha_anchor%402x.gif)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters correct. I *was* shown that in Firefox 31 (which is “uncomfortable” to use, as VNC is slow, and copy/paste between VNC (over VPN) and local does not work).

Comment: This is a Google support issue then; the test works in all modern browsers that Stack Exchange supports.

Comment: Works for me. Are you able to access apis.google.com and www.gstatic.com?

Comment: @Braiam I had JavaScript enabled unconditionally and no filter. I assume they only use their new method for the latest webbrowsers as they probably use some background magic (maybe mouse pointer behaviour monitoring?) for this.

Comment: What browser is that you are using in the screenshot?

Comment: @Braiam opera-9.27-20080331.1-static-qt.i386-en.tar.gz

Comment: Err.... as Martin said above Opera 9 **is not supported** (and I'm almost sure Google don't support this feature in Opera 9 either). Use something more *actual*.

Comment: s/actual/current/ but there is nothing better on my OS :(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how crappy Opera 9 is and the solution would be for the SE network to use an alternate verification method, which for a handful of users that use an unsupported browser seems a bit unlikely.

Comment: I ran into these captchas just now. I tried four in a row and had no luck. I also tried the audio captcha, and it didn't work in my broswer. Maybe it's unfortunate that this question deals with two different things: impossible captchas and opera support. Should we perhaps spin off a separate question about the impossible captchas?

Comment: The site works with Opera just fine, except those impossible CAPTCHAs… some of the people commenting derailed that though.

Comment: @mirabilos: How about just editing out the part of the question about opera support? It hardly matters that captchas are broken in opera, considering that the captchas are simply impossible to solve, regardless of one's choice of browser.

Comment: They are *not* broken in Opera. I never said that. They are just impossible.