# A box is now a CAPTCHA

Tags: bug, status-completed, captcha, wording

The [new CAPTCHA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244726/152859) got has a small wording bug:

[image]

That should probably be reworded to:

> "Check the CAPTCHA box, and we'll be out of your way.:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, thanks for the report!  Box captcha is something I'd rather not check.

Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Now it'll be great ;) Btw, I thougt it should be "checkboxed captcha" :)