# cannot post because of CAPTCHA

Tags: support

I've had severe difficulty all day posting to Stack Overflow. I'm behind a firewall at a state agency. I frequently get timeouts and other problems. I post and it says there was an error posting. I submit again, same thing. I found if I copy the text to the clipboard, refresh the page, then paste and submit immediately, it usually works.

Then comes the next difficulty layer. It asks if I'm a robot. I check the box, try to decipher, and click ok. I usually can't figure out what the letters are. I refresh several times for new letters. I call people to my desk to help, and together we often don't get it right.

The final problem is, I often get an error saying it cannot get to the CAPTCHA server. At that point I have to start over.

Today I spent over half an hour trying to post an answer and was unable. I have work to do. I can't spend all day playing with this. When I post a question I try to answer two or three others so I can give back. But I can't! I can't make it work!

After half an hour and time to leave, I emailed the URL and verbiage home. Now I am home. I CANNOT MAKE OUT THE LETTERS ON THE CAPTCHA TO POST MY REPLY. This is extremely frustrating.

I do a lot of web stuff. This is the worst capcha I've seen. I can't believe it's so hard. Please help if you can.

Comment: The capcha prompt does not seem to appear for new questions, only replies I make to other questions.

Comment: Thanks for helping with my issue. Apparently someone saw my issue. I was just now able to post my reply to stackoverflow and the capcha only asked for three plainly visible digits.

Comment: We pretty much just serve what Google gives us and post it back to them for verification. There's not much we can do if your firewall is that restrictive. We did [implement the new CAPTCHA](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244726/155160), though, which should help with illegible letters... although I'm not sure off the top of my head if we're serving it everywhere or just on questions/ask.